# Socket constructor is the top one among functions allocating more memory list, why?

Tags: .net, sockets, memory, profiling

I am developing a .NET framework to develop peer-to-peer applications. In the previous version I did it with the APM pattern (BeginXXX/EndXXX) and it worked perfectly. I mean, I measured with the VS profiler and the results were the expected ones, no surprises.

Currently I am updating it to use the hight performance improvements introduced in .NET 3.5, it is XXXAsync. The framework works okay however, when I see the profiler's results (about memory usage) the Socket constructor is the top 1 in the "functions allocating most memory"!

Just a side comment: I expected that the second one, ConnectionIoActor, would be the top one because it creates a new bytes[1<<16] (64Kb).
[image]

I´ve tested it with only two sockets: the listener and an incomming connection and am sure the socket constructor was not in the top of that list before the refactoring. It doesn´t make any sense for my, the constructor is simply the same one!

Anyway, if that does not make sense for you neither, why is the socket constructor allocating that memory?

**UPDATE 1:**

connections are the expected ones:
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

The problematic socket seems to be the one listening for connections.

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE 3:**

With this code a could reproduce it. In the Main method I allocate a 100kb array just to be sure what I see is okay and it is.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace SocketMemeoryTest
{
    class Listener
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var forComparison = new byte[100*1024];
            new Listener(3453).Start();
        }

        private readonly IPEndPoint _endpoint;
        private readonly Socket _listener;

        public Listener(int port)
        {
            _endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            _listener = new Socket(_endpoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            _listener.SetIPProtectionLevel(IPProtectionLevel.Unrestricted);
            _listener.Bind(_endpoint);
            _listener.Listen(4);
            var saea = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            var async = _listener.AcceptAsync(saea);
        }
    }
}
```

Look, the listener socket is using a lot more memory than any other socket (what could be okay, i don't know).

This is what I see:

[image]

Probably I am misunderstanding something but anyway, almost 150kb. Could this be okay? 
Note: in the real project, after connect to it, the listener socket requires more than 200Kb.

Comment: Can you get a count of *how many* socket objects are being created? That would be my next step.

Comment: two: in fact I have a performance counter that increments itself every time a new connection is accepted (even when it is a redundant counter - the system already provides it)

Comment: Okay, that seems extremely odd. Are you able to reproduce this with a short but complete program at all?

Comment: I have to do that, I know. I will do it and come back with it. I hope to be able to reproduce it.

Comment: how many bytes is it actually allocating?  It may be a high percentage but still not that much in the grand scheme of things..

Comment: I´ve updated the question with code and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The memory allocation is due to System.Net.Logging which is used by System.Net.Socket constructor. Disabling System.Net logging may help. IMO there is nothing to worry about.